# Request Translation to English

Tags: translation

Chinese(?) Scroll.  Request translation to English.  I’m assisting an elderly friend who grew up in S. Korea.  She had this (among others) beautifully mounted writing hidden away in a closet.  She cannot translate.  Please assist.  Curious about the value, as well.  Thank you[image: SCROLL]

Comment: Just want to add, it should be sentimental value rather than much monetary value.  Its like knowing someone very good at painting who isn't famous or worth a lot of money, its still quite nice :)

Comment: I agree with you and thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

the text maybe “日落沙逾白 雲移水更淸 高人弄明月 只欠紫鸞笙” which is a poem “漢浦弄月” by 李穡

“maybe” is, some characters are hard to recognise, according to chinese (too cursive lah )

the left-most, smaller text is “菊浦”, most likely a place name, “朴亨”, the name of the calligrapher; “書” roughly “written [by]”

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and information!